# From my website, how can i get linkedin's cookie's JSESSIONID value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

From my website, how can i get linkedin's cookie's JSESSIONID value?

reference site: https://app.we-connect.io/signup

If it is not possible then can someone guide me:

1) how above ref. website has validated linkedin's credentials on their website?
2) the process about how ref. website get the token?

Thanks

Look at this attached images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAKH0.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzpn4.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/APSA6.png

Comment: It's not possible to access a third party cookie, for security reasons. To answer your questions: #1 Through LinkedIn's [OAuth integration](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow#). #2 see #1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access cookies from another website. If this were the case, any authentication related tokens could be easily grabbed from other websites, which would be a massive security vulnerability.

This may help with creating a linked social login button:
https://coderwall.com/p/ejayxg/javascript-linkedin-social-login-button-for-oauth-io

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your purpose but maybe you should have a look at Linkedin's documentation about "Sign In with LinkedIn" :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin

Hope this would help.